# Why i cannot import java.util.Date.* package in eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, jsp, import

here are the code and I got error import the date package in eclipse, as shown I got error to import the date package in my ide, can you please help me to solve the problem, is that any problem with my jdk or what ?

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.Date.*"%>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Using Java’s object in JSP page.</title>
</head>
<body>
 Display Current Date

 <%
Date todayDate = new Date();
out.print("Current date and time is " +todayDate.toString() + " " );
%>
</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: I have tried to use java.util.Date, but still error

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you report that you're getting an error, it is very important to tell us exactly what the error is.  You've only said you're getting an error, and you told us nothing about what error you're getting.

However, I think it's pretty likely that you should change "java.util.Date.*" to "java.util.Date".

Comment: it's okay, I found the way to solve it. thank you for your comment